# Stop individual timer using Angular Timer

Tags: angularjs, timer

I have an app using [Angular Timer](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer) though **I'm having trouble stopping a single timer**. When I click timeout on the first, timer it stops them all.

Basically, I make individual timer base on the name of an employee as follows:

index.html

```
...
<md-card class="md-padding">
  <md-content-card>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Employee</label>
    <md-select ng-model="employeeName">
      <md-option ng-repeat="employee in employees" value="{{employee.name}}">
        {{employee.name}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
  <center>
  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary md-hue-2" ng-click="startTimer()">Time In</md-button>
  </center>
  </md-content-card>
</md-card>

<md-card ng-repeat="(key, value) in times">
  <md-content-card>
  <center>
    <h2>{{ value.employeeName }}</h2>
    <h3>Time In At: {{ value.date | date: 'medium' }}</h3>
    <h3>
      <timer interval="1000">{{hours}} hour{{hoursS}}, {{minutes}} minute{{minutesS}}, {{seconds}} second{{secondsS}}.</timer>
    </h3>
  <br>
  <md-button class="md-raised md-accent md-hue-2" ng-click="stopTimer()">Time Out</md-button>
  </center>
  </md-content-card>
</md-card>
...
```

app.js

```
angular
  .module("HomeApp")
  .controller("HomeCtrl", function ($scope){
    $scope.employees = [
      {name: "Jerald"},
      {name: "Arnie"},
      {name: "Junnie"},
      {name: "Gilbert"}
    ];

    $scope.times = [];

    $scope.startTimer = function (){
        $scope.times.push({
          employeeName: $scope.employeeName,
      date: new Date()   
        });
    };

    $scope.stopTimer = function (){
        $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
    };

    $scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, data){
        console.log('Timer Stopped - data = ', data);
    });

  });
```

[image]

Comment: Can you change the `stopTimer` implementation to use `this.$broadcast` and see if it works. Since ng-repeat creates new scope it may, Check here too https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer/issues/166

Comment: While I am not familiar with this timer, I would think it works like any other in that you can assign it a specific ID at creation in your ng-repeat. You could then pass that ID along with your stop broadcast and target only that timer instead of killing all of them.

Comment: @Chandermani Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Let me add it as an answer then, an you can mark the question answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular timer is based on the event raised on the scope of controller. If there are multiple timers defined on a single scope all of then get started and stopped together.

You are lucky here as you are using `ng-repeat` here which creates a new scope, and the timer is nested inside it.

You just need to access this scope to raise events that stop the specific timer.
When the event handler for the button is called `this` points to the scope of the `ng-repeat` so this works

```
  $scope.stopTimer = function (){
        this.$broadcast('timer-stop');
    };
```